# SwiftUI CoreData how to delete row and save context

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to delete a row from my CoreData entity but it always returns this error, what am I doing wrong?

Error Log

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
```

CartViewModel.swift

```
class CartViewModel {
    var managedObjectContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Cart.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Cart.menuName, ascending: true)
        ]
    ) var cartItems: FetchedResults<Cart>

    func deleteItem(at index: Int) {
        print(index)
        let cart = cartItems[index]
        managedObjectContext2.delete(cart)
        PersistenceController.shared.save()
    }

    func addToCart(menuCode: String, menuName: String, menuImg: String) {
        let newCart = Cart(context: managedObjectContext)
        newCart.menuCode = menuCode
        newCart.menuName = menuName
        newCart.menuImg = menuImg
        
        PersistenceController.shared.save()
        
        print(newCart)
    }
}
```

Persistence.swift

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    /*** Default code from new project ***/

    func save() {
        let context = container.viewContext

        if context.hasChanges {
            print("CHANGE")
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Show some error here
                print("ERROR")
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        } else {
            print("NO CHANGES")
        }
    }
}
```

The function addToCart works perfectly and added the new item into Entity, but deleting a row always return error. What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it this line, `let cart = cartItems[index]`, that causes the crash? How is the delete method called? _Edit_ oh wait, now I see the problem. You can’t use `@FetchRequest` in a normal class so your array is always empty, only in a View. Replace it with a normal NSFetchRequest

Comment: yes, that line is actually causing the crash, it is just called as it is, how is it supposed to be called?

Comment: I tried adding this func in the VM: func getCartItems() { print(cartItems) }, and it is printing FetchedResults<Cart>(results: <__NSArray0 0x7fff8002e970>(

), does it means it failed to fetch? however looping the same code in CartView returns the data

Comment: See my updated comment. Do you also have a @FetchRequest in the view?

Comment: Yes I do have @FetchRequest in the view, could you please make an answer with how to use the @NSFetchRequest? it returns this error: Unknown attribute 'NSFetchRequest', it might help other newbies such as me

Comment: Read up on using NSFetchRequest (without a @), there are plenty of examples online. But in general it is a bad design to have two arrays of fetched elements at the same time so another option is to send the actual object from the view to the delete method and then delete it directly. Or move the delete code to the view.

Comment: I'm implementing MVVM, therefore separating the delete function in VM, yes, researching about NSFetchRequest right now, thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Ok, good. Remember that if you implement a NSFetchRequest in your view model then make the result array @Published and use it as your only data source so no fetch request in the view